# Using Math.Attan2() to find the angle of a single line against a center line

Tags: javascript, atan2

I have an svg line that is drawn based on the (x, y) coordinates of 2 separate points. I want to take that drawn line and use the [Math.Atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) method to find it's angle.

Ie:

- Above the center line = positive angle
- Below the center line = negative angle

For my application, there will be no scenario where the points (a, b) will be on the same horizontal side. So the liner will always cross the imaginary vertical(y axis) centerline.

I have my functions working right now, but for some reason, the angle seems off, as well as being inversed. I stumbled upon this method after going down a rabbit hole of trying to do this with Pythagorean theorem, but this seems like a more out-of-the-box solution.

Am I misunderstanding how Math.Atan2 is supposed to work?

```
const getDegreeOfLine = (pointa, pointb) => {
    p1 = pointa.getBoundingClientRect();
  p2 = pointb.getBoundingClientRect();

    return Math.floor(Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI);
}
```

Is the answer as simple as just inversing the returned result?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jk65wd0/1/)

Comment: SVG doesn't use the mathematical coordinate system. It has an "upside down" y axis (compared to the mathematical y axis).

Comment: Yeah the coordinate system is likely your only issue, the angles themselves look to be correct. This reference may help visualize the coordinate system. https://docs.aspose.com/svg/net/drawing-basics/coordinate-systems-and-units/

Comment: @RaymondChen, I see.. So what I'm seeing based off of that means my best best might be to flip the entire SVG container so that it mimics a cartesian coordinate system?

Comment: Or just flip the y coordinates when you do your math.

Comment: Actually, that might be easier, since flipping the SVG would need the drawing logic to be refactored to some extent. If you want to add that as an answer, I can accept it, thank you!

Comment: @Nickofthyme this helped demystify it for me, thank you for sharing!